# Data gets added to curl's retrieved content

Tags: c++, curl

I am using CURL with C++ to get the source code of websites, I am putting the content in a string with a function, but I get extra data (a 0 and a few new lines)

Here's my code (this isn't the whole code as the project is a bit big)

This is the function to get the content/put it into a string

```
size_t writefunc(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, string pContent)
{
    pContent += (char *)ptr;
    return size*nmemb;
}
```

And here is how I initialize the CURL object

```
string Content;
CURL *pCURL = curl_easy_init();
if(!pCURL)
{
    cout << "Couldn't create a curl object" << endl;
    return 0;
}
curl_easy_setopt(pCURL, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writefunc);
curl_easy_setopt(pCURL, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_easy_setopt(pCURL, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie_file.txt");
curl_easy_setopt(pCURL, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &Content);
curl_easy_setopt(pCURL, CURLOPT_POST, true);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something more meaningful. You can remove C++ and curl (because they're both in the tags), which leaves your title as *extra data*, and that has zero value. Your title should describe the actual question you're asking or problem you're experiencing in a way that will have relevance to future readers who see it in a search result. Thanks.

Comment: That callback doesn't look write. How can you pass it `string` (by value) as the last parameter when it asks for `void*` as the last parameter. You need to then cast that `void*` to an `string*` and call `str->append(ptr)`. At the very least, the last parameter should be `string* pContent`.

Comment: KenWhite : done, thanks. @Brandon : I have tried a few things, even if it compiled and worked, the result was the same. Are you sure that the problem comes from there ?

Comment: Can you post the URL? The easiest way to debug this is to put: `std::cout.write(static_cast<char *>(ptr), size * nmemb)` in your callback function `writefunc`. If it prints the entire source of the webpage, then yes the `pContent` is the issue.

Comment: The problem is here with any website, I just tested it with http://www.website.com/ and it still happened. But not in the console (it printed the entire source without extra data), so yes the problem comes from the parameter I'm giving... as I already have tried a few things but still can't seem to make it work correctly, may you please tell me exactly what I need to write ?

Comment: I see the problem. You are setting: `CURLOPT_POST` to `true`. You should NOT do that if you are trying to do a `GET` request which is what a browser does to `get` the webpage's source code. `POST` is usually for logging in or sending data. Some servers let you `POST` with parameters and they send back data. But that's not the case when you are trying to get a webpage's source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested on OSX El-Capitan 10.11.4 - Xcode 7.3. Works.

--

**Note:**
If you need SSL connection, just add `#define USE_SSL` and change the verification (`CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST`) if you need to guarantee that the peer or host has proper certificates.

You also do not NEED a lot of the options I have specified in the code below..

**EDIT:** I see the problem in your code. You are doing a `POST` request. What you really want is a `GET` request since you want to get the source of the web page.

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  TestCurl
//
//  Created by Brandon T on 2016-04-21.
//  Copyright © 2016 XIO. All rights reserved.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>


size_t writefunc(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    std::string *page_source = static_cast<std::string *>(userp);

    if (page_source)
    {
        page_source->append(static_cast<char *>(contents), size * nmemb);
    }

    return size * nmemb;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    std::string page_url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36757217/data-gets-added-to-curls-retrieved-content?noredirect=1#comment61096734_36757217";

    std::string user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36";

    std::string page_source;


    CURL *curl_handle = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl_handle)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, user_agent.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writefunc);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &page_source);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1L);

        #ifdef USE_SSL
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_USE_SSL, CURLUSESSL_TRY);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);  //2L
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);  //2L
        #endif

        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");

        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, page_url.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 0L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 0L);

        CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);

        if (res != CURLE_OK)
        {
            std::string error_message = curl_easy_strerror(res);
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);

            std::cerr << error_message;
            return 0;
        }

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);

        std::cout << page_source;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

**Result:**

```
*   Trying 104.16.35.249...
* Connected to stackoverflow.com (104.16.35.249) port 80 (#0)
> GET /questions/36757217/data-gets-added-to-curls-retrieved-content?noredirect=1 HTTP/1.1
Host: stackoverflow.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Cookie: __cfduid=ddbf5d3e848c27dcbc1fded421106e2311461286187; prov=b57e8199-4ea1-4ad3-a9bb-cad71f707835

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 22 Apr 2016 00:59:16 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=60
< Expires: Fri, 22 Apr 2016 01:00:16 GMT
< Last-Modified: Fri, 22 Apr 2016 00:59:16 GMT
< Vary: *
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-Request-Guid: 36d372e7-2da8-4c7f-ab22-ecd8cb96fa39
< Server: cloudflare-nginx
< CF-RAY: 297521d23dac016a-ORD
< 
* Connection #0 to host stackoverflow.com left intact
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QAPage">
<head>
```

plus the source code for this page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also need to make post requests sometimes, but yeah maybe I should switch the default to get. Anyway I will try your code. :)

Comment: Thanks again, this works. I didn't change the post request to a get request tho, I think it was only coming from the callback function. Even if you told me what to do, I guess I didn't write it correctly.